# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this question has been asked before but I can't seem to get mine to work.

```py
import numpy as np


def load_dataset():
    def download(filename, source="http://yaan.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/"):
        print ("Downloading ",filename)
        import urllib
        urllib.urlretrieve(source+filename,filename)

    import gzip
    
    def load_mnist_images(filename):
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
            download(filename)
        with gzip.open(filename,"rb") as f:
            data=np.frombuffer(f.read(), np.uint8, offset=16)
            
            data = data.reshape(-1,1,28,28)
            
            return data/np.float32(256)

        def load_mnist_labels(filename):
            if not os.path.exists(filename):
                download(filename)
            with gzip.open(filename,"rb") as f:
                data = np.frombuffer(f.read(), np.uint8, offset=8)
            return data

        X_train = load_mnist_images("train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz")
        y_train = load_mnist_labels("train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz")
        X_test = load_mnist_images("t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz")
        y_test = load_mnist_labels("t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz")

        return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test


X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_dataset()


import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show(plt.imshow(X_train[3][0]))
```

This is the error I am getting:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nehad\Desktop\Neha\Non-School\Python\Handwritten Digits 
Recognition.py", line 38, in <module>
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_dataset()
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

I am new to machine learning. Did I just miss something simple? I am trying a Handwritten Digit Recognition project for my school Science Exhibition.

Comment: `load_dataset()` doesn't return anything, so by default, it returns `None`, which you can't unpack. Maybe you're thinking about doing `return load_mnist_images("""some-filename""");`? But then you'd need a file name.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think your `X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test` are defined inside your `load_mnist_images`function, and are thus not defined for your `load_dataset` function.

You should de-indent your 5 lines from `X_train = ...` to `return X_train, ...` and your code might work better then.

Comment: Declaring multiple variable in a row comma separated was the issue for me. In other languages *like VB* using the comma syntax makes the variables variant types (not a bunch of ints).

Answer (score 45):

You get this error when you perform a multiple assignment to `None` (which is of `NoneType`). For instance:

```
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = None
```

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

So if you get this, the error is most likely that the right-hand part of the assignment is not what you expected (it's nothing).

Comment: If you still want to use one line, you can do this: X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = None, None, None, None.

Answer (score 6):

Splitting/breaking multiple assignment to None resolves this issue.

e.g. This DOESN'T work:

```
test_set_raw, test_set_transformed, train_set_raw, train_set_transformed = None
```

This DOES work (no error):

```
test_set_raw = None
test_set_transformed = None
train_set_raw = None
train_set_transformed = None
```

Answer (score 3):

You get that error because `load_dataset()` returns `None`.

run this and you get the same error:

```
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = None
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code: plt.show(plt.imshow(X_train[3][0]))
Add: coma before the last closing bracket, this error is showing because you're using a tuple and tuple receive coma after the last element or item in it.
Do this: plt.show(plt.imshow(X_train[3][0]),)