# "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AsyncResult object" while using Django?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I'm using Django with Celery to make an async call that returns multiple values. However, when trying to unpack these variables in my Django view, it throws up the TypeError mentioned above. Here's what I have so far:

### Relevant Code

`views.py`

```
def render_data(request):
    reddit_url = request.POST.get('reddit_url')
    sort = request.POST.get('sort')
    var1, var2 = celery_run.delay(reddit_url, sort)
    data = {
        'var1': var1,
        'var2': var2,
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

`tasks.py`

```
@shared_task
def celery_run(reddit_url, sort):
    var1, var2 = run_data(reddit_url, sort)
    return var1, var2
```

### Expected Result vs Actual

Ideally, the function would properly unpack and each variable would be assigned to the proper value from the function. Instead, I receive a typeerror indicating that I can't unpack async objects. I'm not entirely sure, but is that because I'm trying to unpack from a function thats still running?

### What I've tried

1. Unpacking variables within tasks.py instead in views.py, did absolutely nothing but I prayed
2. Followed the solution from [TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680913/typeerror-cannot-unpack-non-iterable-nonetype-object) but unfortunately extra indents makes my code work less

If I could get any info on what causes this error and the best method to approach this, I'd be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can return a list that has `var1` and `var2`?

Comment: It seems you want to run `celery_run` synchronously. In that case just try to use: `var1, var2 = celery_run(reddit_url, sort)`

Comment: @clerkvector112 did you manage to sovle this?