# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object (after number of iterations)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

When ever maximum number of iterations (max_n) were smaller than 34 , I get TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object . But if its bigger than 34 there's no problem it works just fine . I would like to also get what happens between 0-34 iterations . Whatever I tried seems not working .

```
import numpy as np 

def gauss_seidel (A , b , X0 = None , tol = 1.e-8 , max_n = 3, w = 1.):
    
    (m,n) = A.shape 
    
    # Initialising number of iteration
    k = 1
    #Define starting vector 
    if X0 == None:
        X0 = np.zeros(shape = n)
        nIt = 0
        x = X0.copy()
        w = 1.
        #Loop to calculate Gauss_Seidel
    while k <= max_n :
        for i in range (n):
            s = 0
            for j in range (i):
                if (i==j):
                    continue
                else:
                    s += A[i][j]*X0[j]
            for j in range (i + 1 , n):
                if (i==j):
                    continue
                else:
                    s += A[i][j]*x[j]
            X0[i] = (w*(-s + b[i])) / (A[i][i])
            #Calculates error , here I used residual norm (x_currentstep-x_previousstep)
            err = np.linalg.norm(X0 - x)
            #Checks error condition
            if (err < tol):
                return X0 , nIt
            #Incrementing k
            k += 1
            #Updating parameter
            for i in range(n):
                x[i] = X0[i]


A = np.array([[4 ,-1 , 1] , [-1 , 4 , -2] , [1 , -2 , 4]])
b = np.array([[12] , [-1] , [5]])

x = np.ones(shape = 3)

from scipy import linalg
x = linalg.solve (A,b)


(x,its) = gauss_seidel (A , b , tol = 1.e-8 , w = 1.0)

print ('Lösüng nach {} Iterationsschritten : {}' .format (its,x))


print (x)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 10>()
      6 from scipy import linalg
      7 x = linalg.solve (A,b)
---> 10 (x,its) = gauss_seidel (A , b , tol = 1.e-8 , w = 1.)
     12 print ('Lösüng nach {} Iterationsschritten : {}' .format (its,x))
     15 print (x)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

1
​
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you post the full error message including the stack trace?

Comment: I have just updated

Comment: Much like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680913/typeerror-cannot-unpack-non-iterable-nonetype-object?rq=1 your `gauss_seidel` method doesn't have an explicit return, so it returns None, which you can't unpack.

Comment: but why does it work for the max_n > 34 ?

Comment: It looks like you do have one place where `gauss_seidel` returns a value, but if it doesn't make it to that line of code, it will return `None`.